# Setting bootstrap dropdown width equal to container

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a left aside which is `260px` wide and a right aside which is `260px` wide. My center div is fluid `100%` width.

On the click of the right arrow/center div, i want to have a `dropdown` of the same width of the center div container. Below is my code and `fiddle`.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">    
   <div class="row">
    <div class="leftBox pull-left" href="#">
      <img src="//placehold.it/258x58">
    </div>
    <div class="rightBox pull-right" href="#">
      Right Div
    </div>
     <div class="centerBox">
       <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">
              <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></b></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <form class="form" id="formLogin"> 
                  <input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"> 
                  <input name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"><br>
                  <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn">Login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/82O0SgmP8p

Comment: Do you want with only CSS or are you OK to use Javascript/jQuery? Since you have tagged jQuery, can I assume you are ok with a jQuery solution?

Comment: @Harry: I am just thinking on how we can make the drop-down menu width equal to the center div container width. I am ok with any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a jQuery based solution which calculates the `width` of the center box (both on `load` and during window resizing) and then assigns the `width` to the login box and also positions it as appropriate.

**Note:** Refer comments inline for explanation of the steps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cntrboxWidth = $('#centerBox').width()-520; // Width of center box minus width of the two side boxez
  $('#navLogin + .dropdown-menu').width(cntrboxWidth); // Setting the width of Login box
  var extraWidth = $('#navLogin').outerWidth(); // Getting the width of the arrow icon box to adjust position
  $('#navLogin + .dropdown-menu').css('left',-(cntrboxWidth)+extraWidth); // Positioning the login box

  $(window).resize(function(){ // Adjusting position and size upon resizing window.
    cntrboxWidth = $('#centerBox').width()-520;
    $('#navLogin + .dropdown-menu').width(cntrboxWidth);
    extraWidth = $('#navLogin').outerWidth();
    $('#navLogin + .dropdown-menu').css('left',-(cntrboxWidth)+extraWidth); 
  });

});
```

[**Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/ozCUefvSn8)

**EDIT:** To position the login box exactly below the menu, use the below CSS. It need not be dynamic because as per CSS you have a fixed height (60px) for your menu bar.

```
.dropdown-menu{
    top: 60px; // Equal to the height of the menu
}
```

Comment: Thanks Harry again, can you make the drop-down start align exactly to the end of the menu. it overlaps a bit top... as show in image.

Comment: Thanks Harry again, one final question... Do you think the layout i am going is correct or should i go ahead and change with grid-based system. Its a navbar btw

Comment: Can we achive the same with css without using jQuery if possible?

Comment: Might be possible but difficult considering the width calculation and dynamic positioning.

Comment: @theJava: I assume you were referring to the arrow button. It went down a line because the first line is a block. For both to be in same line you need to make it as inline-block. Check [this](http://www.bootply.com/6jkX0OdBZm). I have added the last two lines to the CSS for positioning. But I think it maybe time for you to get  some expert advise from anybody who has used bootstrap to see if there are any other built in designs to address these. (Note: I have deleted some of the past comments to make the conv shorter).

Comment: Can you help me in this thread, when free. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745623/aligning-the-user-icon-and-user-name-to-left

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) instead of floating the columns right and left?

With the grid you can do something like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 width-260">
            <!-- left box goes here -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <!-- centre box goes here -->
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3 width-260">
            <!-- right box goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then place your dropdown in the centre column. It'll be far easier to style that way (i.e. make it `width: 100%` of the containing element etc).

All you would then have to do is add some custom styles which make sure the right and left columns are fixed at `260px`

**Update:** To make the right and left columns 260px fixed width, add this to your style sheet:

```
.width-260 {
    width: 260px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, can you help me in making the left and right column to 260px and center to 100% width with the grid system in place. Thanks again.

Comment: See my update. Also note I've added a `width-260` class to each of the columns (left and right). The centre column should already be fluid by default.